# RemoveHandler for DatePicker in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, handler

i am using VB.Net and my form contains DatePicker control, and i come to know the following thing

**Code 1**

```
RemoveHandler DatePicker1.Validating, New EventHandler(AddressOf DatePicker1_Validating)
```

**Code 2**

```
RemoveHandler DatePicker1.Validating, AddressOf DatePicker1_Validating
```

but both have different behaviour.can anyone exaplain the difference ?

Comment: Does the 1st line compile? I haven't worked on vb.net but I doubt that the 1st line is correct.

Comment: The first line will remove the handler of the newly created handler and that should be used for AddHandler.

Comment: @shahkalpesh yes 1st line will work.

Comment: @Jade - both will remove event handler for DatePicker but in different manner. what was that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines do the same thing i.e. They have the same outcome.

The difference is that in the first line:

```
RemoveHandler DatePicker1.Validating, New EventHandler(AddressOf DatePicker1_Validating)
```

You create a new instance of an `EventHandler` and set the address to point to the existing `DatePicker1_Validating` event. All this does is create a extra object to be garbage collected at some point later so is less efficient that the second method:

```
RemoveHandler DatePicker1.Validating, AddressOf DatePicker1_Validating
```

which passes a reference to the already existing handler with no intermediate object